# How to get keyboard strokes only from a specific child process with C#

Tags: c#, .net, keyboard

I would like to ask if it is possible to capture the keyboard strokes of a user in a specific child process by using C# and .NET.

I have found many articles related to GLOBAL keyboard capturing where you can monitor the keyboard and capture every key stroke regardless of the process running.

I want to capture the keyboard strokes for a specific child process that I create from my main application.

For example, my main application is a console application and at some time spawns a new process for Microsoft Word. I want to get the keystrokes only from that process.

Comment: That is exactly what I have done so far. But I am facing another problem now. When I open a new word instance both have the same process ID! This is crazy, Windows seems that recycle and share same process ID. I have tried to use also the MainWindowHandle instead of Id or Handle properties. Is there a way to inject a new Guid in the new process and retrieve it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by using the MainWindowHandle property.